# What did Rsync Delete?

Tags: rsync

Uhoh... issued this command:

```
rsync -avv --progress --delete "/media/Drive1_/" "/media/Drive2_/Backup/"
```

Previously, it had been working great and was:

```
rsync -avv --progress --delete "/media/Drive1_" "/media/Drive2_/Backup/"
```

But I added a trailing slash. Now, I'm seeing lots of output like this:

```
deleting /media/Drive1_/pics/pics/somepic.jpg
or
deleting /media/Drive1_/Drive2_backup/pics/somepic.jpg
```

I believe there should only be one /pic/ directory, but it lists two. Navigating to that path in samba shows the jpg serves up just fine.

I want the trailing slash to be there. Does this output though mean that Rsync deleted content from /media/Drive1_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have pasted the "previous" command exactly the same as the "new" one but I will assume the previous one did not have the trailing slash.

When you put a trailing slash at the end of a source directory, rsync treats it as a "contents of this directory". So if you do "rsync pics/ otherdir" you put *contents* of pics into otherdir. If you do "rsync pics otherdir", you would put the directory pics into otherdir.

In the destination directory there is no difference whether you put trailing slash or not. If the directory doesn't exist, it will get created. Depending on the existance of trailing slash after source directory, it will either have contents of source in it or the source directory in it.

Example:

`rsync -avv /media/drive/backup/ /media/drive2/backup`

is the same as

`rsync -avv /media/drive/backup /media/drive2`

Comment: Good assumption. I fixed that, thank you. Thus even though stdout says it is deleting /media/Drive1_..., it appears my files are still intact on Drive1. So Drive1 should be intact with these commands, correct?

Comment: In your case, you have probably just "moved" the files. You deleted /pic/pic and copied everything to /pic or vice versa. It probably took some time, right?